# Open Delphi ZLib compressed data with c#

Tags: c#, delphi, stream, zlib

I have a lot of files made with an application written in Delphi that I want to open in a C# application. I'm currently writing.

The 'old' Delphi code that unpacks the files is:

```
InputStream := TFileStream.Create(InputFileName, fmOpenRead);
OutputStream := TMemoryObjStream.Create;
DecompressionStream := TZDecompressionStream.Create(InputStream);
OutputStream.CopyFrom(DecompressionStream, 0);
```

This is the code I use to open these files in c#:

```
FS = new System.IO.FileStream(File, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
System.IO.MemoryStream MS = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
ZLibNet.ZLibStream ZS = new ZLibNet.ZLibStream(S, ZLibNet.CompressionMode.Decompress);
ZS.CopyTo(MS);
ZS.Close();
FS.close();
```

If I now start to read the "MS-stream" with a binary reader
I get some strange data in the first 24 bytes, and after that I get values that seem to be logical.
First it should read an Int32 which it does and which has a sensible value.
After that a string, this string is displayed as "\0\0\0ISua" where I expect "ISuarez". But if I move the stream position one byte further I get "Suarez\n\0\0\0"
This makes me wonder if I might start reading the stream some bits later instead of bytes, but how to do this?

Comment: This is zlib rather than ZIP. I think you need to work out what headers are present in the compressed files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept this problem on the shelve for a while and recently did another attempt to solve it and found out what was wrong:

Delphi writes a 32bit integer for the length of the string followed by the characters.

Binaryreader.Readstring in .Net on the other hand, reads a byte and multiplies it by 7 to get the length of the string, that declares why my first 3 characters where null characters "0\"

so I wrote my own stringreader:

```
enter code here
        private String ReadString(System.IO.BinaryReader BR)
    {
        Int32 StringLength = BR.ReadInt32();
        Char[] Chars = BR.ReadChars(StringLength);
        return new String(Chars);
    }
```

And this works fine.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Hi we had a similar problem. Zlib is not Zlib in .Net. We found over 10 Libs which hat "zlib" label on it, but where not able to compress/uncompress in the same way like delphi does.

We endet in using the nuget package "zlib.net" in version 1.0.4.0.
That worked for us.

Answer (score 0):

The real question is what is compressing your data, which you don't show, but:

I had a scenario where I was compressing data in Delphi and needed to read it in C#.  It was a simple matter of skipping the first two bytes, because the zlib library in Delphi uses two bytes in the header that the Deflate routine in C# doesn't.